# Multi Auth methods Apache http client 4.3+

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a few servers with different Auth types. Basic, NTLM. I need mechanism to select it automaticly. I see that as trying with each credential type, and select that was successful. I found some method in http client 4.3, named impl.client.HttpClientBuilder#setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry, but

1. I have no idea how to use that.
2. Second question, how I can control priority of auth methods. Because I want to determine which method for the url I should use, and then want to start from successful method on last request.

PS as for now i have workable realization for each type of auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can configure preferred auth schemes on a per request basis using `RequestConfig`

```
RequestConfig requestConfig =  RequestConfig.custom()
        .setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC))
        .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.NTLM, AuthSchemes.DIGEST))
        .build();
```

Local execution context contains all the details pertaining to request execution including auth state for target and proxy hosts

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
    try {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        AuthState targetAuthState = localContext.getTargetAuthState();
        if (targetAuthState.getAuthScheme() != null) {
            System.out.println("Target auth scheme: " +
                    targetAuthState.getAuthScheme().getSchemeName());
        }
        AuthState proxyAuthState = localContext.getProxyAuthState();
        if (proxyAuthState.getAuthScheme() != null) {
            System.out.println("Proxy auth scheme: " +
                    proxyAuthState.getAuthScheme().getSchemeName());
        }

    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Comment: One usually should have no need to do so. HttpClient automatically re-uses the last known successful authentication scheme _provided_ requests share the same execution context